# how to update a leaky integrate and fire neuron

Tags: c++, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a leaky integrate and fire neuron in C++, but can't figure out a good and efficient way to update the neuron's voltage when a new current arrives.

I am using this code write now, but I am new to the field and don't think it is an optimal solution. Is that the right way to update a neuron?

```
void LIF_neuron::update(double current, size_t time){
    //update current
    //formula: (V_current - V_reset)*(1-exp((t_last_fired - t_now)/RC)) + R*I
    mCurrentVolt += -1*(mCurrentVolt-mResetVolt)*(1-exp((mLastTimeFired-time)/mRC)) + mR*current;

    //all leakage since last activation was substracted, give back what was already substracted in earlier updates
    mCurrentVolt += (mCurrentVolt-mResetVolt)*(1-exp((mLastTimeFired-mLastTimeUpdated)/mRC));

    if(mCurrentVolt >= mThreshold){
        mFires = true;
        mLastTimeFired = time;
    }else{
        mFires = false;
    }

    mLastTimeUpdated = time;
}
```

`mRC` and `mR` are constants of the neuron.

Comment: not a single line of C++ in sight...

Comment: sorry, I updated my question, I try to write my program in C++, but any pseudocode or formulas would help me

Comment: ...what have you tried? SO is for concrete code, not pseudocode or concepts.

Comment: If you want to really code easily and concentrate on grasping concepts of neural networks I would suggest matlab, and there are numerous examples of integrate and fire neuron models in matlab for e.g. [here](http://neuroscience.ucdavis.edu/goldman/Tutorials_files/Integrate%26Fire.pdf)

Comment: I will look through the matlab code, thanks